# Dynamically set mat-select-options when using ngx-mat-select-search in formArray in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have a formArray which contains two mat-selects. One of them uses [ngx-mat-select-search](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-select-search) to search from the values in the options of the mat-select. My problem is that when the form array contains multiple elements, and I search in one of the mat-select from these elements, the value from all the mat-selects disappears while I'm searching and it reappears after a value has been selected.
Here is the portion of my template file:

```
<ng-container formArrayName='cpUserAccounts'
                        *ngFor='let account of cpUserAccounts.controls; let i=index'>
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap col-md-12" [formGroupName]='i'>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <mat-form-field class="task-array">
                                    <mat-label>Client</mat-label>
                                    <mat-select formControlName="clientId" required>
                                        <mat-option>
                                            <ngx-mat-select-search [formControl]="bankFilterCtrl"
                                                placeholderLabel='Search' noEntriesFoundLabel="'No match found'">
                                            </ngx-mat-select-search>
                                        </mat-option>
                                        <mat-option *ngFor="let client of filteredOptions | async" [value]="client.id">
                                            {{client.companyName}}
                                        </mat-option>
                                    </mat-select>
                                    <mat-hint class="error"
                                        *ngIf="findDuplicate(account.controls.clientId.value, 'cpUserAccounts')">
                                        {{constants.errorMessage.duplicateClientLabel}}
                                    </mat-hint>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <mat-form-field class="task-array">
                                    <mat-label>Role</mat-label>
                                    <mat-select formControlName="roleId" required>
                                        <mat-option *ngFor="let role of accountRoles" [value]="role.id">
                                            {{role.name}}
                                        </mat-option>
                                    </mat-select>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2 d-flex justify-content-end">
                                <mat-icon class="remove-task-button" title="Remove" (click)='removeAccount(i)'
                                    matSuffix>
                                    remove
                                </mat-icon>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ng-container>
```

and the .ts file contains the following code:

```
filteredOptions: ReplaySubject<ClientModel[]> = new ReplaySubject<ClientModel[]>(1);
public bankFilterCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();
protected onDestroy = new Subject<void>();

ngOnInit() {
      this.bankFilterCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy))
      .subscribe(() => {
      this.filterBanks();
            });
    }

getClients() {
        const subscription = this.clientContactService.getClients().subscribe(clients => {
            this.clients = clients.data;
            this.filterBanks();
        });
        this.subscription.push(subscription);
    }

protected filterBanks() {
        if (!this.clients) {
            return;
        }
        // get the search keyword
        let search = this.bankFilterCtrl.value;
        if (!search) {
            this.filteredOptions.next(this.clients.slice());
            return;
        } else {
            search = search.toLowerCase();
        }
        // filter the clients
        this.filteredOptions.next(
            this.clients.filter(client => client.companyName.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1)
        );
   }
```

Here are the images of the flow of what is happening:
In the starting, it is like this:
[image]

Then:

[image]

The problem is here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using the `filteredOptions | async` element whithin `*ngFor`, the same options will be used for each "client"-select element displayed. Hence when filtering, it will filter the options of all client select boxes, and thus the originally selected value is not available anymore.

To resolve this, you could move the content of the outermost `*ngFor` to a separate component, which should implement the ControlValueAccessor interface (https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor#description).

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in this too and couldn't find any solution anywhere then came up with this on my own. The simplest way to do this is by using a backup FormControl with array as value. and accessing its value in the template array where you want to use the array. Try to undertand this simple code example -

```js
export class FormExampleComponent {
  public formGroup: FormGroup;
  public itemCodesArray: ItemCode[] = [
    { id: 1, name: apple },
    { id: 2, name: banna },
    { id: 3, name: pineapple },
  ];
  
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {}
  
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createForm();
  }

  private createForm() {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      formItems: this.fb.array([this.initFormGroup()]),
    });
  }

  private initFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      description: [null, []],
      formItemsGroup: this.initFormItemsGroup(),
    });
  }

  private initFormItemsGroup(): FormGroup {
    const fg = this.fb.group({
      // id is just to recognize the form array elemnts by trackByfunction
      id: [new Date().getTime() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)],
      itemCodeSearch: [null, []],
      // temp array 
      filteredItemCodes: [this.itemCodesArray, []],
      itemCodeId: [null, [Validators.required]],
      itemDescription: [null, [Validators.required]],
    });

    fg.get('itemCodeSearch')
      .valueChanges
      .subscribe((searchText) => {
        this.itemCodes$.subscribe((itemCode) => {
          if (searchText) {
            fg.get('filteredItemCodes').setValue(
              itemCode.filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())),
            );
          } else {
            fg.get('filteredItemCodes').setValue(itemCode);
          }
        });
      });

    return fg;
  }
  
  public get formItems(): AbstractControl[] {
    return (this.formGroup.get('formItems') as FormArray).controls;
  }
  
  public trackByFunction(index: number, item: any): number {
    return item.value.formItemsGroup.id;
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <div formArrayName="formItems">
    <div *ngFor="let formItem of formItems; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFunction">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <div>
          <div formGroupName="poItemsGroup">
          
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
              <input type="text" matInput formControlName="description" required />
            </mat-form-field>
              
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <mat-label>Item Code</mat-label>
              <mat-select formControlName="itemCodeId" required>
                <mat-option>
                  <ngx-mat-select-search
                    formControlName="itemCodeSearch"
                    placeholderLabel="Search item"
                    noEntriesFoundLabel="No item found"
                  ></ngx-mat-select-search>
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option
                  *ngFor="
                    let item of formItem.get('formItemsGroup').get('filteredItemCodes').value;
                    trackBy: 'id' | trackByKey
                  "
                  [value]="item.id"
                >
                  {{ item.name }}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
            
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <mat-label>Item Description</mat-label>
              <input type="text" matInput formControlName="itemDescription" required />
            </mat-form-field>
              
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Since valueChanges fire too often you can use debounceTime to stop it from firing on every single character user enters. 
You can also use OnDestroy lifecycle hook along with takeUntil function to unsubscribe every subscription to make it more effecient.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this problem?

Comment: @Asmithaj.s I've already mentioned the solution.